# How to prove combination of $n$ objects equivalent in two forms?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I come across the problem of all the choices of selecting a subset of $n$ objects.

When expressed in binary form, seems very clear that there are $2^n$ subsets.

But when using combination, it comes to this result:

$$ \sum_{x=0}^n \frac{n!}{(n-x)! x!} = \sum_{x=0}^n \binom{n}{x} . $$

How do we prove those two are equivalent? If they are indeed so?

$$ \sum_{x=0}^n \frac{n!}{(n-x)! x!} = 2^n $$

Comment: The fact that both expressions count the number of subsets of $n$ objects is itself a proof (see [combinatorial proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_proof)). If you instead want an algebraic proof, you can look at $2^n = (1+1)^n$ and expand the right-hand side.

Comment: Thanks. They answer beautifully